# Python SQLAlchemy Flask Sqlite can open database only from "python crud.py". When imported while the app is running, it cant open the database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

app.py

```
from pprint import pprint
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from restApi import crud
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/aad')
def hello_world():
    return "hello world"

@app.route('/')
def hello_worldp():
    return render_template("index.html")


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"prova": "sono una prova"}


api.add_resource(HelloWorld, "/HelloWorld")
api.add_resource(crud.ProvaApi, "/c")
api.add_resource(crud.getAllColumns, "/allColumns")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

test.py

```
    from pprint import pprint
    
    from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload
    from flask import  jsonify
    from data import  schema
    def test1():
        c = schema.Colonne(titolo="prova5", stato="boh")
    
        cont1 = schema.Contenuto(testo="prova Contenuto1")
        cont2 = schema.Contenuto(url="nonsourl")
    
        t = schema.Tile(titolo="provaTile", autore="nonso", contenuto=cont1.id)
        t2 = schema.Tile(titolo="provaTile", autore="nonso", contenuto=cont2.id)
        session = schema.dbSession()
    
    
       # c.tile.append(t)
        #c.tile.append(t2)
        #c.tile[0].contenuto.add(cont1)
        #c.tile[0].contenuto.add(cont2)
       # session.add(c)
        #session.commit()
    
        colschema = schema.ColonneSchema()
        tileschema = schema.TileSchema()
        contschema = schema.ContenutoSchema()
        qr = session.query(schema.Colonne, schema.Tile, schema.Contenuto).\
            select_from(schema.Colonne).\
            join(schema.Tile, schema.Colonne.titolo == schema.Tile.colonna_id, isouter=True).\
            join(schema.Contenuto, schema.Tile.contenuto == schema.Contenuto.id, isouter=True).all()
        #qr = qr.filter(schema.Colonne.titolo == "prova5")
        #record = qr.one()
        print(qr)
        #ti = record.tile.get(0).filter(schema.Tile.id == 1)
        #ti.contenuto.add(cont1)
        qp = session.query(schema.Tile);
        qp = qp.filter(schema.Tile.id == "1")
        record = qp.one()
    record.contenuto = cont1.id
    session.commit()

    qr = session.query(schema.Colonne, schema.Tile, schema.Contenuto). \
        select_from(schema.Colonne). \
        join(schema.Tile, schema.Colonne.titolo == schema.Tile.colonna_id, isouter=True). \
        join(schema.Contenuto, schema.Tile.contenuto == schema.Contenuto.id, isouter=True).all()
    for r1, r2, r3 in qr:
        print(colschema.dump(r1))
        print(tileschema.dump(r2))
        print(contschema.dump(r3))



def test2():
    c = schema.Colonne(titolo="prova4", stato="boh")
    t = schema.Tile(titolo="provaTile", autore="nonso")
    t2 = schema.Tile(titolo="provaTile", autore="nonso")
    cont = schema.Contenuto(testo="prova Contenuto", url ="nonsourl")
    session = schema.dbSession()
    c.tiles.append(t)
    c.tiles[0].contenuto = cont
    dum = schema.ColonneSchema().dump(c)
    #print(c.tiles[0].contenuto)
    #print(dum)

    #c.tiles.append(t2)
    #c.tiles[0].append(cont)
    session.add(c)
    session.commit()

    #tiles

    #cols = session.query(schema.Tile).all()
    # print(jsonify(cols))
    #t_schema = schema.TileSchema()
    # print(c_schema.dump(cols))
    #for col in cols:
        #   print(jsonify(col))
    #    print(t_schema.dump(col))
def test3():
    session = schema.dbSession()
    query = "select Colonne.titolo, Colonne.stato, Tile.id, Tile.autore, Tile.contenuto, Contenuto.testo,Contenuto.url" \
            " from Colonne inner join Tile" \
            " on Colonne.titolo = Tile.colonna_id left join " \
            "Contenuto on Contenuto.id = Tile.contenuto;"

    rs = session.execute(query)
    #row_headers = [x[0] for x in rs.description]
    resultset = [dict(row) for row in rs]
    print(resultset)

    #for row in rs:
     #   print(jsonify(row))
def test4():
    query="insert into Contenuto values ('gna', 'codio')"
    session = schema.dbSession()
    rs = session.execute(query)
def test5():
    query = "SELECT * FROM Contenuto"
    session = schema.dbSession()
    rs = session.execute(query)
    presultset = [dict(row) for row in rs]
    print(presultset)


def test6():
    session = schema.dbSession()
    rs = session.execute("PRAGMA  foreign_keys;")
    for row in rs:
        print(row)
def test7():
    session = schema.dbSession()
    rs1 = session.query(schema.Colonne).select_from(schema.Colonne).join(schema.Tile).join(schema.Contenuto).all()
    rs = session.query(schema.Colonne).all()
    scCol = schema.ColonneSchema(many=True)
    print(scCol.dump(rs))
    #for row in rs:
    #    print(scCol.dump(rs))
def test8():
    c = schema.Colonne(titolo="prova4", stato="boh")
    t = schema.Tile(titolo="provaTile", autore="nonso", colonna = c)
    t.colonna = c
    cont = schema.Contenuto(testo="prova Contenuto", url="nonsourl")
    t.contenuto = cont
    rs = schema.ContenutoSchema().dump(cont)
    pprint(rs)
    rs = schema.ColonneSchema().dump(c)
    pprint(rs)
def test9():
    session = schema.dbSession()
    rs = session.query(schema.Colonne).all()
    pprint(schema.ColonneSchema(many=True).dump(rs))
def test10():
    session = schema.dbSession()
    colonne = session.query(schema.Colonne).all()
    dizionario = {}
    rs = schema.ColonneSchema(many=True).dump(colonne)
    tileSchema = schema.TileSchema()
    contenutoSchema = schema.ContenutoSchema()
    pprint(rs)
    listaTot= []
    listaColonne = []
    for col in colonne:
        dizionario = {}
        print("***************COlonna********************")
        print(schema.ColonneSchema().dump(col))
        listaTile = []
        dizionario['colonne'] = schema.ColonneSchema().dump(col)
        for tile in col.tile:
            print("***************Tile********************")
            #pprint(tileSchema.dump(tile))
            print("***************Contenuto********************")
            #pprint(contenutoSchema.dump(tile.contenuto))
            print("***************Contenuto********************")
            print("***************Tile********************")
            tiletmp= tileSchema.dump(tile)
            tiletmp['contenuto'] = contenutoSchema.dump(tile.contenuto)
            listaTile.append(tiletmp)
        dizionario['tile'] = listaTile
        print("***************COlonna********************")
        listaTot.append(dizionario)
    return listaTot
def test11():
    session = schema.dbSession()
    colonne = session.query(schema.Colonne).all()
    dizionario = {}
    rs = schema.ColonneSchema(many=True).dump(colonne)
    tileSchema = schema.TileSchema()
    contenutoSchema = schema.ContenutoSchema()
    pprint(rs)
    listaColonne= []
    for col in colonne:
        print(schema.ColonneSchema().dump(col))
def test12():
    sess = schema.dbSession()
    r=sess.query(schema.Colonne).filter_by(titolo="prova4").first()
    sess.delete(r)
    sess.commit()
    print(r)
def test13():#update
    sess = schema.dbSession()
    r=sess.query(schema.Colonne).filter_by(titolo="prova4").first()
    r.titolo ="provagay"
    sess.add(r)
    sess.commit()
    print(r)
def test14():#cancella elemento
    sess = schema.dbSession()
    r=sess.query(schema.Tile).filter_by(id="1").first()
    sess.delete(r)
    sess.commit()
    print(r)
def test15():#update elemento
    session = schema.dbSession()
    c=session.query(schema.Colonne).filter_by(titolo="prova4").first()
    t = schema.Tile(titolo="provaTile", autore="nonso")
    t2 = schema.Tile(titolo="provaTile", autore="nonso")
    cont = schema.Contenuto(testo="prova Contenuto", url ="nonsourl")

    c.tiles.append(t)
    c.tiles[0].contenuto = cont
    dum = schema.ColonneSchema().dump(c)
    #print(c.tiles[0].contenuto)
    #print(dum)

    #c.tiles.append(t2)
    #c.tiles[0].append(cont)
    session.add(c)
    session.commit()

def query_to_dict(ret):
    if ret is not None:
        return [{key: value for key, value in row.items()} for row in ret if row is not None]
    else:
        return [{}]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pprint(test10())
```

schema.py

```
from flask import Flask
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy.fields import Nested
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, scoped_session, sessionmaker, joinedload,backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema, fields
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///../database/mydb.db', convert_unicode=True)

dbSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                        autoflush=False,
                                        bind=engine,
                                        ))

ma = Marshmallow(app)
class Colonne(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Colonne"
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    titolo = Column(String, unique=True)
    stato = Column(String)
    tile = relationship("Tile", back_populates ="colonna", cascade="all,delete")


class Tile(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Tile"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    autore = Column(String)
    titolo = Column(String)
    colonna_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Colonne.id"))
    colonna = relationship("Colonne", backref="tiles", overlaps="tile")
    contenuto_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Contenuto.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    contenuto = relationship("Contenuto", backref="tile", cascade="all,delete")
class Contenuto(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Contenuto"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True )
    testo = Column(String)
    url = Column(String)



class ColonneSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Colonne


class TileSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Tile

    colonna = Nested(ColonneSchema)


class ContenutoSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Contenuto
        include_fk = True
        include_relationships = True
        load_instance = False

    tile = fields.Nested(TileSchema)
# -----------------------crea tabelle----------------------------


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

crud.py

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from data import schema
from pprint import pprint


def getColonne():
    session = schema.dbSession()
    colonne = session.query(schema.Colonne).all()
    dizionario = {}
    rs = schema.ColonneSchema(many=True).dump(colonne)
    tileSchema = schema.TileSchema()
    contenutoSchema = schema.ContenutoSchema()
    # pprint(rs)
    listaTot = []
    listaColonne = []
    for col in colonne:
        dizionario = {}
        # print("***************COlonna********************")
        # print(schema.ColonneSchema().dump(col))
        listaTile = []
        dizionario['colonne'] = schema.ColonneSchema().dump(col)
        for tile in col.tile:
            # print("***************Tile********************")
            # pprint(tileSchema.dump(tile))
            # print("***************Contenuto********************")
            # pprint(contenutoSchema.dump(tile.contenuto))
            # print("***************Contenuto********************")
            # print("***************Tile********************")
            tiletmp = tileSchema.dump(tile)
            tiletmp['contenuto'] = contenutoSchema.dump(tile.contenuto)
            listaTile.append(tiletmp)
        dizionario['tile'] = listaTile
        # print("***************COlonna********************")
        listaTot.append(dizionario)
    return listaTot
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pprint(getColonne())
class ProvaApi(Resource):
    def get(self):

        return {"prova": "sono una prova"}

class getAllColumns(Resource):
def get(self):
    return getColonne()
```

Now, when i run "python crud.py" `getColonne()`works.
Otherwise when the endpoint is being called,while the app is running, "getAllColumns", it can't open the database *sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file*.

the structure is something like this:
project
data
schema.py
database
mydb.db
restApi
crud.py
test
test.py
app.py

And of course while running all the test.py i dont have problems.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a relative path in your `create_engine()`. Using an absolute path will resolve your issue. If it's important that it be relative to the file, use something like `create_engine(f"sqlite:///{os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'database/mydb.db')"})`.